# Is it possible to write an Ethereum dapp that uses Monero?

Tags: decentralization, gaming

Thinking about writing a dapp that uses Monero for playing games. Will probably be hosted on Ethereum. Won't accept non-privacy coins.It would send back Ether tokens pegged to the current value of Dai.